# Performing MySQLi searches that contain URL encoded strings

Tags: php, select, mysqli, field, url-encoding

I am having trouble retrieving data from a database, when the field contains a URL encoded string.

What I mean is, my MySQLi database contains a field called "artist_name", where some of the values contain URL encoded strings, such as:

- "Sonny+O&#39;Brien"
- "Lil&#39;+Joe"
- "Batman+&amp;+Robin"

etc.

When I search on these fields in PhpMyAdmin, it finds them straight away, using a select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `artists` WHERE `artist_name` LIKE 'Sonny+O&#39;Brien';
```

However, when I try the same thing programmatically, from within my PHP script, it returns no results:

```
$artist_name = "Sonny+O&#39;Brien";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM artists WHERE artist_name LIKE '".$artist_name."'";
if ( $result = $mysqli->query( $sql ) ) {
    $obj = $result->fetch_object();
}
```

No results.

I have tried using an addslashes() on the artist's name, and I have double-checked all the value's and I am providing them exactly as they appear in the database.

Any ideas why the URL escaped strings are not recognised in my SELECT queries?

edit:
[image: screenshot]
(screenshot from PhpMyAdmin, showing that my data is stored as described, and that my SELECT query works from within PhpMyAdmin, just not from my PHP script).

Comment: That's not URL-encoding, it's HTML entities.

Comment: Actually, it looks like both. `+` is URL-encoding for space, but `&amp;` is HTML entity for `&`.

Comment: The right solution is to NOT put encoded text into the database in the first place. URL-encoding should just be used when putting the value in a URL parameter, HTML entities should be used when displaying on a web page. Store the raw data in the DB, and encode when needed.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification, however this shouldn't affect the question. I know what the values are, I can see them in the database using PhpMySQL, but I can't retrieve them using a PHP query.

Comment: Are you converting to entities to avoid SQL injections? Use parameterized queries. `GET`/`POST` are URL decoded on the PHP side so your query probably is `Sonny O&#39;Brien`.

Comment: I don't think it should make a difference, but why are you using `LIKE` instead of `=`? The name doesn't have any wildcards in it.

Comment: No, it's a legacy database, I am just trying to clean up. I can't change the 250,000 records that are already in there, I just need to be able to select on that field.

Comment: Are you really assigning `$artist_name` from a literal like that, or is it something like`$artist_name = $_GET['artist'];`? URL encoding is automatically decoded when getting values from `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Comment: No real reason for using LIKE instead of "=". Just that I was getting no results with "=", so I tried LIKE to widen the search. Just stabbing in the dark really.

Comment: Actually, "artist_name" is coming out of another table, and is already encoded like that. I am doing a SELECT on the first table, assigning $artist_name = $obj->artist_name, then executing the code exactly as above.

Comment: Then I can't think of why it wouldn't work. But why aren't you just using a `JOIN` to relate the two tables, instead of separate queries?

Comment: Question updated to include a screenshot from PhpMyAdmin. Good point @Barmar, a JOIN query might get around the problem, although doesn't really solve it... might do for now though...

Comment: Try 'echo $sql;'` to be sure that the query is exactly what you think it is.

Comment: Yes, done that, and it does...